# Jquery ui datepicker previous button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker

```js
var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
      from = $( "#from" )
        .datepicker({
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          numberOfMonths:2
        })
        .on( "change", function() {
          to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
        }),
      to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths:2,
  minDate:'12/20/2017',
        maxDate:'2M,9D',
   })
      .on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
      });
 
    function getDate( element ) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
      } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
      }
 
      return date;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<form>
   <label for="arrivalDate">Arrival</label>
   <input type="text" name="arrivalDate" id="from" autocomplete="off">
   <br>
   <br>
   <label for="departureDate">Departure</label>
   <input type="text" name="departureDate" id="to" autocomplete="off">

</form>
```

In departure text box after changing month to March ,to navigate back we have to click twice on previous button.Please find the link of issue on fiddle.
 http://jsfiddle.net/dineshn/jp0muxro/1/

Comment: Please find the link: https://jsfiddle.net/dineshn/jp0muxro/1/

Comment: This doesn't fix the bug, but one solution is to set `numberOfMonths:1`

Comment: @JayA.Little But the requiremnt is for 2 months only can you please provide another solution to fix this issue.

Comment: after brainstorming i change the jquery ui version to 1.9.2 and the issue got solved  and its working as per expected output.

Comment: @JayA.Little the issue got fixed after changing the jquery ui version to 1.9.2 there is not need to change numberOfMonths:1 as you mentioned in the comment.

Comment: That's good. I knew my suggestion was only a work around, not a real answer. You can answer your own question though so that its documented for anyone else who runs into the same problem.